# My method is sending HTML instead excel file

Tags: c#, html, .net, excel

This is my method, but my response is a simple HTML, I just duplicated a successful code inside method2 inside ExportReportChip() and it doesn't work

```
public ActionResult SuccessFulMethod(DateTime reference, MobileFilter? filter)
{
    var itens = GetAccountModel(reference, filter);
    var text = "";
    GridView gv = new GridView();
    var products = new System.Data.DataTable("table");
    products.Columns.Add("Referência", typeof(string));
    products.Columns.Add("Número", typeof(string));
    products.Columns.Add("Funcionário", typeof(string));
    products.Columns.Add("Empresa", typeof(string));
    products.Columns.Add("Particular", typeof(string));
    products.Columns.Add("Total", typeof(string));
    products.Columns.Add("Status", typeof(string));
    products.Columns.Add("RDESP", typeof(string));

    foreach (var i in itens.Mobiles)
    {
        var reimbursementid = i.ReimbursementId;

        if (i.TotalEnterprise == 0)
            text = "Sem RDESP";
        else
        {
            if (i.CurrentState == WorkFlowState.Approved)
                text = "Com RDESP";
            else
                text = "Aguardando";
        }

        products.Rows.Add(itens.Bill.Reference.ToString("MM/yyyy", CultureInfo.CurrentUICulture),
            i.PhoneNumber,
            i.Employee.Name,
            i.TotalEnterprise.ToString("C", CultureInfo.CurrentUICulture),
            i.TotalParticular.ToString("C", CultureInfo.CurrentUICulture),
            i.Total.ToString("C", CultureInfo.CurrentUICulture),
            i.CurrentState,
            text
            );
    }

    gv.DataSource = products;
    gv.DataBind();
    Response.ClearContent();
    Response.Buffer = true;
    Response.AddHeader("content-disposition", "attachment; filename=Contas_de_Celular: " + ".xls");
    Response.ContentType = "application/vnd.ms-excel";
    Response.Charset = "";
    StringWriter sw = new StringWriter();
    HtmlTextWriter htw = new HtmlTextWriter(sw);
    gv.RenderControl(htw);
    Response.Output.Write(sw.ToString());
    Response.Flush();
    Response.End();


    return RedirectToAction(ACCOUNT_VIEW_NAME);
}
```

This is the method that returns HTML

```
public ActionResult ExportReportChip()
{
    var items = GetMobileChipsOwner();
    GridView gv = new GridView();
    var products = new System.Data.DataTable("table");
    products.Columns.Add("Chip", typeof(string));
    products.Columns.Add("Dono", typeof(string));
    products.Columns.Add("Serviços", typeof(string));
    products.Columns.Add("Status", typeof(string));
    products.Columns.Add("DependenteX", typeof(string));

    products.Rows.Add("1212121", "dono", "service Teste", "i.Status", "i.DependentName");

    gv.DataSource = products;
    gv.DataBind();
    Response.ClearContent();
    Response.Buffer = true;
    Response.AddHeader("content-disposition", "attachment; filename=Contas_de_Celular:"+".xls");
    Response.ContentType = "application/vnd.ms-excel";
    Response.Charset = "";
    StringWriter sw = new StringWriter();
    HtmlTextWriter htw = new HtmlTextWriter(sw);
    gv.RenderControl(htw);
    Response.Output.Write(sw.ToString());
    Response.Flush();
    Response.End();


    return RedirectToAction(CHIP_REPORT_VIEW_NAME);
}
```

so, this is the return in chrome:

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/r0xgO.png)

Comment: `:` is not valid in a file name.

Comment: This will always return HTML, you can name it as a .xls and Excel may open it but its *not* an Excel file, its HTML.

Comment: Why are you writing to the `Response` *and* returning a redirect?  That doesn't make any sense.  Just return a `FileResult`.

Comment: But the SuccessFulMethod() works great, without any exception

Comment: I take off the ":" and didn't work, the successful method works and another doesn't

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got it.

I changed my Ajax to window.location

look:

```
window.location = "/MyController/ExportReportChip";

/*
$.ajax({
url:"/mobile/ExportReportChip",
data:{},
type:"POST"
}).done(function(result){

}).fail(function(){

});
*/
```

it worked !